# dialog and load() in ie8

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a page (test.html) with a link to a dialog (dialog.html), that then loads a listview (list.html). This works in all browsers except ie7 and ie8. If I then make the dialog a separate page (test2.html) it loads the list fine in ie7 and ie8.

I have tried to debug with `console.log()` to find out what gets executed, and when dialog.html is loaded from test.html in ie8, none of the javascript from dialog.html is executed.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

---

Two minimal/simplified examples that represents my problem:
https://zero3.dk/guru/testing/test.html
https://zero3.dk/guru/testing/test2.html

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" type="text/css">  
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="dialog.html">Open dialog</a>
</body>
</html>
```

dialog.html

```
<div data-role="dialog">
<script>
$('#lp-list').load('list.html',function(){
$(this).trigger("create");
});
</script>
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<h1>Lokationsvælger</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" id="lp-list">
</div>
</div>
```

list.html

```
<ul data-role="listview">
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

test2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" type="text/css">  
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
console.log("1");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="dialog">
<script>
$('#lp-list').load('list.html',function(){
$(this).trigger("create");
});
</script>
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<h1>Lokationsvælger</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" id="lp-list">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by moving all JavaScript from dialog.html to test.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" type="text/css">  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).on('pageinit', function() {
   $('#lp-list').load('list.html',function(){
    $(this).trigger("create");
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="dialog.html">Open dialog</a>
</body>
</html>
```